# Questions regarding this power module

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, dc-dc-converter, buck, output

I'm looking at [this power IC module](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MIC33M650-Data-Sheet-DS20006253A.pdf).

I assume it's a buck converter. In that case, on page 16 of the datasheet, Equation 4.1, there's this formula: Rvout = 8.2 kΩ * TRIM. If TRIM is 5, then what would be the value of Rvout?

Would it be 8.2 kΩ * 5% = 0.41 kΩ or 8.2 kΩ * 5 = 41 kΩ? What happens when I increase to more than 5 %?

Can someone please explain?

Also, there is increased ripple when 41 kΩ is used in series. Can someone also tell me how to reduce this?

There is a higher ripple than in the development phase. The load draw can be changed in frequency but we got a strange ripple at an other frequency than the load is switching, see attachments. CH1 shows V<sub>out</sub> of the MIC33M650, CH2 shows the current drawn from the MIC33M650.

Is it possible to force a PWM mode?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I assume it's a buck converter.

Yes, It is a synchronous buck with on-chip inductor and MOSFETs.

> Would it be 8.2 kΩ * 5% = 0.41 kΩ or 8.2 kΩ * 5 = 41 kΩ?

It's self explanatory:

[image]

For \$\mathrm{TRIM}\%\$ increase, you should place a series resistor of \$\mathrm{TRIM}\$ times \$\mathrm{8.2k}\$. For example, for **5**% higher output voltage, you should place **5** times 8k2 which equals to 41k.

> What happens when I increase to more than 5 %?

You **MUST NOT** exceed +5%, as the datasheet says. But it's not clear but will happen - or at least I couldn't see anything. But it's obvious that the dynamic behaviour will change.

> Also, there is increased ripple when 41 kΩ is used in series. Can someone also tell me how to reduce this?

I'm not sure but the behaviour of the converter might have changed, or you did something wrong. Make sure you placed the correct resistor and you're not disturbing the Vo node.

Normally, as can be seen from many different sync buck block diagrams, error amplifier (E/A) gets the output sample (output voltage divider) from its inverting input, and the ref voltage from its non-inverting input. And there's a compensation network across the output of the E/A and the inverting input. At AC the non-inverting input goes to ground (because it's DC) and the E/A forms an inverting amplifier. Therefore the low-side of the output divider doesn't appear in the transfer function.

So, adjusting the output voltage by playing with the high side resistor of the divider (as done with your chip) reflects directly to the transfer function and therefore any slight adjustment will change the dynamic behaviour of the converter. I don't know if the chip does a digital compensation but even if it does the behaviour still might have changed after adjustment. So that might explain why you see excessive ripple.

But still, as always, make sure that you placed to the correct components and the connections are correct.

Comment: The load draw can be changed in frequency but we got a strange ripple in an other frequency than the load is switching, see attachments. Is there any possibility to reduce this ripple besides a second-stage filter?

Is it possible to force a PWM mode?

Comment: @Newbie I don't see any attachments. If the response speed of the converter is too slow then you can see strange ripple. It's possible to see triangular shape ripple with a frequency of 500 Hz on a 500-kHz-buck converter.

Comment: Hi @Rohat Kilic. I've added the attachments. Please check and let me know what you think.

Comment: Is it possible to force a PWM mode?

Comment: @Newbie I checked the waveforms and, I said in my previous comment, the response speed is slow so the reaction of the converter to load changes is reflected as ripple. It's internally compensated so everything is inside the chip. I don't think you can alter the operation with the external components.

Comment: Oh, in that case, what can I do to reduce the ripple? And also, is it possible to force a PWM mode?

Comment: Remove the external adjustment resistor and see if it helps to reduce the ripple. Because it sure changes the operation. Make sure the components are correct and you're not using a high ESR capacitor as the ripple current times the ESR determines the ripple amount. `And also, is it possible to force a PWM mode?` re-read the last sentence of my last comment above.

Comment: So, I guess we cannot force a PWM mode.

Comment: Kilic, so a PWM mode cannot be forced, right? Could you please clarify this and why it cannot be done? Please

Comment: @Newbie First, I'm assuming you mean CCM/DCM by "PWM mode" (If you don't please clarify what you mean). You don't know what inductance, capacitance, and control method are used inside the chip, so you don't have any control over the chip. It says "constant on time" but switching method changes with load. So no, you can't set the operation mode with the external components. You can force it into CCM though but you don't know what the threshold for CCM is because you don't know the internal component values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification @Rohat Kilic